# Stop Hibernate appending null values to entity on update

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor

I searched many posts of Stack overflow dint find anything much related which helps .

The problem:
I have an entity 
stock
xml file:

```
<class entity-name="stock" table="STOCK">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="ID">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="NAME" type="string" />
    <property name="Type" column="TYPE" type="string" />
    <property name="tax" column="TAX" type="double" />
    <property name="password" column="PASSWORD" type="string" />
</class>
```

I am using hibernate to update table.

The problem when send only required fileds for update from my UI
like

```
[{
"id":2,
  "name": "stock1" 
}]
```

In such case hibernate appends 
nulls to other attributes of the entity
like 
Hibernate Automaticaly genrated nulls for the unchanged columns:

```
  Stock{Type=null, tax=null, password=null,  name=stock1, id=2}
```

Is there a way to avoid this

I tried
this

```
 **dynamic-update** which dint work.
```

I even tried: 
adding interceptor

adding MyInterceptor .
which calls

```
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {

}
```

I read the json to a `List<Map<String, Object>>` using gson.

update code:

```
Session s = this.sessionFactory.withOptions().interceptor(new 
MyInterceptor()).openSession();
Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
if (list.size() != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    s.update(dataEntityName, list.get(i));

                }
            }
tx.commit();
s.close();
```

Is there anything other way to achive this in hibernate ?

Comment: you probably have to change the logic of your update service, can you post the code where you take the json and call update?

Comment: added update code. Kindly tell me if any other details u need. i will update it

Comment: @KishanCS DynamicUpdate should work if you applied that on the entity. Can you tell what was the problem with DynamicUpdate. And of  course, this will be performance expensive if you have to deal with a huge list

Comment: @CrazyMac dynamic-update dint work when i gave it on my class for the above file[xml] Should i configure something else to enable dynamic update appart from specifying inside xml class tag ....dynamic-update="true"

Comment: select-before-update="true" is also not working.

Comment: @KishanCS It should have been an attribute to your class as dynamic-update="true" and ensure the class name is configured with the complete package inside the name attribute